# codes on Palindromes from Guttag's textbook

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I am working through Guttag's book "Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python with Application to Understanding Data ". I couldn't understand his codes for palindromes in figure 4.9 of section 4.3.2.

This is given in the book

```py
def isPalindrome(s): 
   """Assumes s is a str 
      Returns True if s is a palindrome; False otherwise. 
       Punctuation marks, blanks, and capitalization are ignored.""" 

   def toChars(s): 
      s = s.lower() 
      letters = '' 
      for c in s: 
        if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz': 
            letters = letters + c 
      return letters 

   def isPal(s): 
      print('  isPal called with', s) 
      if len(s) <= 1: 
         print('  About to return True from base case') 
         return True 
      else: 
         answer = s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1]) 
         print('  About to return', answer, 'for', s) 
         return answer 

   return isPal(toChars(s)) 

def testIsPalindrome(): 
   print('Try dogGod') 
   print(isPalindrome('dogGod')) 
   print('Try doGood') 
   print(isPalindrome('doGood'))
```

which prints

```py
Try dogGod 
  isPal called with doggod 
  isPal called with oggo 
  isPal called with gg 
  isPal called with  
  About to return True from base case 
  About to return True for gg 
  About to return True for oggo 
  About to return True for doggod 
True 
Try doGood 
  isPal called with dogood 
  isPal called with ogoo 
  isPal called with go 
  About to return False for go 
  About to return False for ogoo 
  About to return False for dogood 
False
```

I don't understand why the function continues after it produces

```py
About to return True from base case
```

and

```py
About to return False for go
```

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: because you are using recursive call, to understand it better, try to make a control flow diagram and then for given example check how the control flow is happening

Comment: @prashantrana Thanks! It is really helpful to write down the control flow on the paper. I was doing it in my mind and I missed the big picture, that's why I didn't see the full recursion.

Comment: hope you get it now